# time.mktime does not accept year before 1900?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python 2.7 time.mktime does not accept year before 1900, this is strange.

```
>>> time.mktime(time.strptime("1/1/1899","%d/%m/%Y"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#293>", line 1, in <module>
    time.mktime(time.strptime("1/1/1899","%d/%m/%Y"))
ValueError: year out of range
```

But the calendar.timegm can do all the values.

```
>>> calendar.timegm(time.strptime("1/1/1899","%d/%m/%Y"))
-2240524800

>>> calendar.timegm(time.strptime("1/1/0001","%d/%m/%Y"))
-62135596800
```

Is this expected behaviour? It is kind of strange to me. It seems not possible to overflow double for just -71 years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

- The first is documented in the [Python 2.7 docs under Year 2000 (Y2K) issues](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/time.html). There it  states

  > Values 100–1899 are always illegal.

  Python 3 supports these dates, so there are no such restrictions ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/time.html)).
- The second point with the negative dates is also expected. The dates are in [seconds since the epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (seconds since 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970). So dates before this are stored as negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have found is related to the platform specific time implementation that `time.mktime` falls back on:

> The earliest date for which it can generate a time is platform-dependent.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.mktime

`calendar.timegm` is a completely separate implementation that happens to operate with time tuples. This tuple stores the entire year so it is able to represent pre 1900 dates easily.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time